# Wordpress is taking over my 404's for another domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

My main domain on cpanel is example.com and my secondary site is hosted on the same server at sample-domain.zzz

But when people go to sample-domain.zzz/404-this-page-wont-exist it ends up taking them to sample-domain.zzz as a HTTP 200 :(

I can't figure out how to prevent this. Basically I need WP to stop taking over my other domains redirects. Hope this makes sense

Comment: Your question lacks details. On which domain is your WordPress running? What makes you think other domains get redirected by WordPress? Depending on your server setup a non-existing url might just be redirected to the base url without showing a 404 page. But you might set up a custom 404 page in htaccess with something like "ErrorDocument 404 /404.html" (You'd also have to create the html file then)

Comment: wordpress is on example.com

Comment: Please share your virtual host configuration as well as any relevant htaccess file.